# finding the x and y coordrinates for every angle within 360 degrees when you have the radius

Tags: python, coordinates, physics, space

I am trying to make a piece of code where it finds the x and y coordrinates for every angle within 360 degrees when you are given the radius i feel like all the maths is correct and the excecution of it is correct however it returns the wrong values when i compare them to the values i put in my calulator

```
import math

print (math.pi)

r = 5

angle = 0
count = 0

while angle <= 360:


    angle_radians = math.radians(angle)

    x_coord = math.cos(angle_radians)*r

    y_coord = math.sin(angle_radians)*r
    print ("Position [",x_coord,",",y_coord,"]")
    angle +=1
    count +=1
    print(count)
```

Comment: Can you add an example of a value that results that is wrong, compared to what you're putting in your calculator?

Comment: 180
Position [ -5.0 , 6.123233995736766e-16 ]

Comment: when i put it in my calculator it gets [-5,0] when i do it in degrees, for the angle of 180degrees

Comment: Did my answer make sense? 6.1e-16 is the same as .000000000000000061. Why does Python have a small error in its floating point calculation? You can find out why here: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-are-floating-point-calculations-so-inaccurate.htm

Comment: Off-topic, but did you notice the capitalized "DO NOT USE THIS TAG!" in the description of the tag [tag:space]?

Answer (score 1):

It's producing the right(ish) answer. Look at the example you gave; the coordinate that looks wrong is the y-coordinate, which should be 0 at a 180-degree turn:

```
6.123233995736766e-16
```

That `e-16` is scientific notation for "times ten to the power of -16". So, that number is equivalent to `.00000000000000006123233...`

Why isn't it returning exactly 0? Because of idiosyncrasies in how Python handles floats.

If you don't need that much precision, you could results more readable by rewriting your function to use `round`, like this:

```
def coords_from_degree(line, angle):
    a = math.radians(angle)
    return (round(math.cos(a)*r, 4), 
            round(math.sin(a)*r, 4)
           )
```

Comment: ok thanks, i was just wondering because i am going to add this to a pygame gui so it plots the orbit, would the super small number not affect it that much?

Comment: Sorry for the cop-out answer, but that kind of depends on how you program it... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your calculator likely has on-board trig functions, or rounds to a certain quantity of digits.  Your given value is *really* small, as Ben Quigley has already detailed.  That happens to be the same value returned by `math.sin(math.pi))`.

The `math` package does a very accurate approximation by summing a quickly-converging series.  Since computers store only a certain number of bits of accuracy, they can't *exactly* represent *every* real number -- they simply round or truncate to the supported number of bits -- likely 64 bits, in this case.

Depending on your needs, you can accept the almost-exact answer, round to a desired number of digits, or do special checks for angles at which you want a result more precise than one part in one quadrillion.